# Why does NHibernate require "protected internal" visibility on auto properties?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

It used to be possible to map auto properties with private setters with NHibernate, but starting with version 3.2 this is no longer the case (not without replacing the entity validator), see [NH dev discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/nhibernate-development/browse_thread/thread/4ec35a22babd3a95).

I understand the `protected` requirement, but why `internal`? This breaks encapsulation, and just feels dirty.

Is the only alternative going back to backing fields?

**UPDATE**: Embarassing but true, it turns out `internal` is not required. So, it's a toss-up between falling back to backing fields or using the protected setter and either avoiding setting values in the constructor or [facing the risk of hard to track bugs](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/Virtual+method+call+in+constructor). Thank you [Fabio](http://groups.google.com/group/nhibernate-development/browse_thread/thread/4ec35a22babd3a95) and @Nexus for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: did you mean "why `virtual`" instead of "why `internal`"?

Comment: no, I meant why `protected internal` instead of just `protected`, if I can't have `private`.

Comment: ok, I was misled by the original title...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Michael,

`public string Foo { get; protected set; }` should still be possible, the dev discussion is about `public string Foo { get; private set; }` which can lead to errors while using lazy properties.

Comment: The proxy validator uses MethodBase.IsFamilyOrAssembly so internal OR protected should work but I don't think it needs both.

Comment: I am pretty sure I tested that, but if you're right, that would be some egg on face. Results in a bit.

Comment: Tested, and updated the question with the results (you were right, thank you!)

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate is quite dirty. It uses reflection in order to access the properties and fields.

You can even map `private` properties and fields as data points.

NHibernate ignores completely the visibility of the elements it needs to access.

Comment: Paulo, how would you map this with NH 3.2: `public string Foo { get; private set; }` ?

Comment: I quite don't remember the code of NHbiernate that queries for the getter and setter of the property. It could be done, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Class{

    public string Foo { get; private set; }

}

Property(class=> class.Foo);
```

You will then need to turn off proxy validation in your configuration:

`Config.Proxy(p => {p.Validation = false});`